# current_cart is undefined when trying to access it from line_items controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make the user redirect_to their current_cart after they click "Add to Cart" link.  I am doing this in the line items controller, and am using railscasts source code as a reference. https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/blob/master/episode-141/store/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb

When I click the "add to cart" link I get this error:

undefined local variable or method `current_cart'

Here is my LineItemsController:

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = LineItem.create!(:cart => current_cart, :product => @product, 

  :quantity   => 1, :unit_price => @product.price)
  flash[:notice] = "Added #{@product.title} to cart."
  redirect_to current_cart_url
  end
end
```

Here is my CartsController:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  def show
  @cart = current_cart
  end
end
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your line items controller is missing a current_cart method:

```
def current_cart
  # where you should find your current cart, i.e.
  @current_cart ||= Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
end
```

Comment: I added that in and I'm getting the same error message.  If you look at the source code I don't think he defines @current_cart

Comment: Actually I meant adding the method above into your LineItems controller. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Now I get this error: Couldn't find Cart without an ID,, I've been looking around for the source but can't find anything. Do you have any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: The session[:cart_id] was only a suggestion. You need to check your code to see where you're storing your cart id when it is created.

Comment: There is a good book on Rails here: https://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails-4